# using php to telnet to a remote device, run show command, then save the output to a file

Tags: php

Our programmer recently left, so my boss has called on me to help with day to day maintenance tasks. I am not a programmer but I have been in the business a long time and usually I can figure my way around most things.

Before he left, our programmer wrote a script for us that logs into all of our Adtran devices and runs some show commands. Then it takes certain parts of that data and adds it to a database. Unfortunately one of the pieces of data, that we now need isn't being extracted. His script runs the command that shows this data, but that particular column of info isn't one of the ones he tagged to be pulled.

So right now I have two options:

- I can go through his code and try to figure out how to use whats already existing to pull the data that I need (since his script already runs the command)
  or
- Start fresh with a new script that does nothing but run the command but then pulls ALL data from that command instead of just certain columns/rows.

Here is the script that he wrote. The command that I need info from is: "show system inventory". I'm trying to pull the part numbers from the cards in these boxes, because some of them are EOL and some are actually being recalled.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

/**
* main class that performs the inventory
*/
class system_inventory
{
  static $cubbyData = array();
  var $ci; //CI variable, CI = cubby inventory?
  var $jobId; // variable for JOB ID

  function __construct() //construct function that
  {
    $this->ci =& get_instance(); // $this-> is access the propery of CI to get the instance of it
    $this->ci->load->library( array('ptelv2') ); //after accessing the instance of CI and load it calls the array ptelv2 for telnet for the function
  }

  static function cubbySet($vars,$arg=NULL) //function called cubbySet
  {
    if(is_string($vars)): //checks to see if $vars is a string
     $vars = array($vars=>$arg); // if $vars is a string it adds it to the array by indicating that $vars is greater than null
   endif;  //ends the if statement

    foreach($vars as $k => $v): // $vars is the array that is the $k (key) to that is equal to or greater than $v (value) IE K points to VARS and v iteration of it
      self::$cubbyData[$k] = $v; // points back to the array cubbyData with the var $k that is references as $vars which is = to the interation of v
    endforeach; //ends for each statement
  }

  static function cubbyGet($i) //function called cubbyGet that is stored in the variable of $i
  {
    return isset(self::$cubbyData[$i]) ? self::$cubbyData[$i] : NULL; // returns to to see if cubbyData index is = to itsself (error checking?)
  }

  static function isolate($nodeIp,$treeIp,$data) //function named isolate that stores varaibles nodeIp,treeIp,and data.
  {
    $targetStr   = $data['topology_tree_detail']; //targetStr is pointing to varaible $data and looking for 'topology_tree_detail'
    $nodeIp      = trim($nodeIp); //trims data to nodeIP
    $needle      = 'Path to Tree Node'; //needle varaible is set to 'Path to Tree Node'
    $pathToPos   = strpos($targetStr,$needle); //resets the path of the POS (position?) to strpos (starting position?) by referencing $targetStr, and $needle
    $targetFound = FALSE; // varaible targetFound set to FALSE?

    while($pathToPos !== FALSE) //while loop that stores $pathToPos (path to position?) as NOT EQUAL TO FALSE
    {
      $targetStr = trim(substr($targetStr,$pathToPos)); //the variable of targetStr is trimming the substrings of targetSttr and pathToPos

      $tmpPos    = strpos($targetStr, "\n"); //the tmpPos (temporary position?) is set equal to the strpos (starting position?) referencing the targetStr, and looking for the character "n"?
      $tmpStr    = substr($targetStr,0,$tmpPos); // the tmpStr (temporary string) is set to the substring of the targetStr (target string), 0, and tmpPos (temporary position) which looks for the "n" character

      $spos      = strpos($tmpStr, $nodeIp); //spos (start/string position?) is set to equal the strpos (String position?) which references the tmpStr (temporary string), and the nodeIP

      if($spos !== FALSE): //checks to see if the $spos is not equal to false
        $ipLen = strlen($nodeIp); // variable of ipLen is equal to strlen (string length) of the nodeIp
        $offset= $ipLen + $spos; //variable of offset is equal to the iplen and the spos variables

        $epos  = strpos($targetStr,$nodeIp,$offset) + $ipLen; //the epos (exponential variable because they are too fucking many fucking variables in here why did the bastard not create objects?) is equal to strpos (starting position) which looks at targetstr,nodeip, and offset then add the ipLen back in
        if($epos !== FALSE): //checks to see if the epos is equal to false
          $targetStr   = substr($targetStr,0,$epos); //the target string is then set to a substring of the targetStr,0, and epos variable
          $targetFound = TRUE; //variable of targetFound is set to true
          break;
        endif; //ends 2nd if statement
      endif; //ends 1st if statement

      $pathToPos = strpos($targetStr,$needle,strlen($needle)); //the variable of pathToPos is set to the strpos (Starting position) that looks at the targetStr,needle and the string length of the needle
    }

    if($targetFound === FALSE): //checks to see if the targetFound is false
      return FALSE;  // returns false if target is not found
    endif; //ends if statement

    $lines = explode("\n",$targetStr); //variable of lines is using the function explode looking for the character "n" in the variable $targetStr
    unset($lines[0],$lines[1]); // the function unset is used to reference lines at the index of 0 and lines at the index of 1 this resets the variable lines back to the original after looking for the "n" character

    $lines = array_values($lines); //variable lines is set to arrary_values of lines
    if(count($lines) <= 1) return FALSE; //checks to see if the count of lines is less than or equal to 1 and if it is then returns false (error checking)

    $matrix = array(); //variable matrix set to an array

    foreach($lines as $k => $line): //start of for each, lines is references as K and is equal to or greater than line
      if($line != ''): // if the variable line is not equal to a " " (space) then the next line will trim the variable line
        $line = trim($line); //see above
        $cols = preg_split('/\s{2,}/',$line); // the variable cols = is splitting the lines variable at "s" and 2

      if(!isset($cols[1])) return FALSE; //the isset is looking at the cols varible at the index of 1 and if cols is set to the index of 1 return false
        $matrix[$k] = array_map('trim',$cols); //the array matrix is looking at the index of $k (lines) and set equal to the array_map to "trim" the variable cols
      endif; // end if
    endforeach; // end for each

    $count = count($matrix); //variable count is set to count the matrix array
    $target= $matrix[--$count]; //target is set to the matrix array and decrementing the count
    $feeder= $matrix[--$count]; //the feeder variable is set to the array matrix and decrementing the count

    $final['nodeindex'] = $feeder[0]; // nodeindex is set to feeder index of 0
    $final['fedbyip'] = $feeder[1]; // fedbyip is set to feeder index of 1
    $final['fedbyslot'] = $feeder[2]; //fedbyslot is set to feeder index of 2
    $final['fedbyport'] = $feeder[3]; //fedbyport is set to feeder index of 3
    $final['uplink'] = $feeder[4]; //uplink is set to feeder index of 4

    $final['nodeip'] = $target[1]; // nodeip is set to target index of 1

    if($final['fedbyip'] != $treeIp): // checks to see if the final feeder index of 1 is equal to the variable of treeIP
      $feederLog = self::fetch_command_results($final['fedbyip']); // the feederLog variable looks at the fetch_command_results and displays the "fedbyip" remark
      $system_inventory = $feederLog['system_inventory']; //  the variable system_inventoryis stored in the variable feederLog as "system_inventory"
      $efmGroup = $feederLog['efm-group']; // the efmGroup is stored in the feederlog as efm-group
    else: //start of else
      $system_inventory = $data['system_inventory']; //system_inventory is set to the variable of datat that is storing "system_inventory"
      $efmGroup = $data['efm-group']; //efmGroup is set to varaible data storing "efm-group"
    endif; //endif

    if(!empty($system_inventory) and preg_match('%1/'.$final['fedbyslot'].'[^,]+,(?P<card>[^,]+)%i', // checks to see if the variable system_inventory is eximpy then runs a regualr expression match that looks for
                  $system_inventory,// place holder of 1/X (variable) drilling into the .$final variable looking for (fed by slot) .
                  $regs)):

      $final['nodeCard'] = trim($regs['card']); // final is looking at nodecard and trimming the variable regs down to 'card'
    else: //start of else
      $final['nodeCard'] = NULL; //if it doesn't exist returns NULL
    endif; // end if

    $final['spans'] = $final['provisioned_links'] = $final['active_links'] = NULL; // variable of final stores spans provisioned_links and active_links setting to NULL

    $targets = array( // variable targets is set to an arry with outputting interface efm-group 1/ (referencing the $final variable ) which stored the fed by slot and fed by port indexes to see where it is being fed by
      "interface efm-group 1/{$final['fedbyslot']}/{$final['fedbyport']}",
      'Provisioned Links',
      'Active Links',
      'Inhibited'
    );

    $target = current($targets); //variable target set to current $targets variable

    if( ($pos = strpos($efmGroup,$target)) !== FALSE ): // if the pos variable is set to the starting positing of emfGroup and target then it is not equal to false then it will offset (stored in a varialbe)
      $offset = strlen($target) + $pos; //then will determine the string length of target and add the pos to the length of the string
      $target = next($targets); // then will set the variable of target to the next instance of $targets after determing the string length and starting position
      if( ($pos = strpos($efmGroup,$target,$offset)) !== FALSE ): // checks to see if the starting position is set to the starting position of emfGroup,target,and offset not equal to false
        $offset = strlen($target) + $pos; // then offsets the string length of target and adds it to the varibale pos (position?)
        $target = next($targets); // then adds it to the target variable
        $epos = strpos($efmGroup,$target,$offset); // the epos variable is set to the staring position of emfGroup,target,and offset

        $text = substr($efmGroup,$pos,($epos - $pos)); // the variable text is being set to the substring of variables efmgroup,pos, and the epos - pos
        $text = trim($text); // then the text variable trims the text to equal :
        $x = explode(':',$text); // see above
        $text = trim($x[1]); //text variabe is trimmed to match the x variable so that the x resides with just x:
        $text = preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/',',',$text); // looks for the pattern ofr "/[\r\n]+/" then replaces it with , , in the text variable
        $x = explode(',',$text); // breaks the variable text into a array by using the ","
        $x = array_map('trim',$x); // x after exploded set to an array_map and will trim, variable of X
        $final['provisioned_links'] = implode(',',$x); // after array_map the final will look for provisioned_links and add the , to the variable x

        $pos = $epos;
        $offset = $pos + strlen($target);
        $target = next($targets);
        $epos = strpos($efmGroup,$target,$offset);
        $text = substr($efmGroup,$pos,($epos - $pos));
        $text = trim($text);
        $x = explode(':',$text);
        $text = trim($x[1]);
        $text = preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/',',',$text);
        $x = explode(',',$text);
        $x = array_map('trim',$x);
        $final['spans'] = count($x);
        $final['active_links'] = implode(',',$x);
      endif;
    endif;

    return $final;
  }

  function get_system_version($nodeIp)
  {
    $data = self::fetch_command_results($nodeIp);

    if($data === FALSE or empty($data['version'])):
      return FALSE;
    endif;

    $version = '';
    //will need to get version from the node ip itself, not parent
    if(preg_match('%1/[0-9]+\s([a-z]+[0-9]+)\s[^\s]*%im', $data['version'], $regs)):
      $version = $regs[1];
    endif;

    //check system inv for number slots to
    //determine ta5000 or ta5006
    if($version != ''):
      preg_match_all('%1/([0-9]+)\b%im', $data['system_inventory'], $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
      $slots = isset($result[1]) ? $result[1] : NULL;
      if(is_array($slots) and (int)end($slots) == 6 and stripos('TA5000',$version) !== FALSE):
        $version = 'TA5006';
      endif;
    endif;

    return $version != '' ? $version : FALSE;
  }

  static function get_conn_args($ip)
  {
    $vars = array(
      'host' => $ip,
      'user' => 'xxxxxx',
      'pass' => 'xxxxxx',
      'port' => '23',
      'debug'=> 0,
    );

    return $vars;
  }

  static function fetch_command_results($ip)
  {
    $sectioned_log = self::cubbyGet($ip);

    if(empty($sectioned_log)):
      $t = new ptelv2();
      $args = self::get_conn_args($ip);

      if($t->connect($args) == FALSE):
        return FALSE;
      endif;

      $full_log = '';
      $sectioned_log = array();

      //get top tree topology and system inventory first
      $t->enable();
      $t->DoCommand('show topology tree detail');
      $t->more(0,TRUE);

      //break it up into sections for easier parsing
      $full_log .= $t->response_log;
      $sectioned_log['topology_tree_detail'] = trim($t->response_log);

      //reset after breaking into sections
      $t->response_log = '';

      $t->DoCommand('show system inventory');
      $t->more(0,TRUE);

      //break it up into sections for easier parsing
      $full_log .= $t->response_log;
      $sectioned_log['system_inventory'] = trim($t->response_log);

      //reset after breaking into sections
      $t->response_log = '';

      $t->DoCommand('show version');
      $t->DoCommand('break');

      //break it up into sections for easier parsing
      //break it up into sections for easier parsing
      $full_log .= $t->response_log;
      $sectioned_log['version'] = trim($t->response_log);

      //reset after breaking into sections
      $t->response_log = '';

      $t->DoCommand('show interface efm-group');
      $t->more(0,TRUE);

      $full_log .= $t->response_log;
      $sectioned_log['efm-group'] = trim($t->response_log);

      //reset after breaking into sections
      $t->response_log = '';

      $t->quit();
      $full_log .= $t->response_log;

      $sectioned_log['full_log'] = $full_log;

      self::cubbySet($ip,$sectioned_log);
    endif;

    return $sectioned_log;
  }

  function main()
  {
    $rev = 5;
    $misfits = array();

    $this->ci->db->query("DELETE FROM `tool_system_inventory`");


    $query = $this->ci->db->order_by('company ASC, ipaddress ASC')
                      ->get_where('dslams',array('deleted'=>0));

    if( $query->num_rows() == 0 ):
      //exit;
    endif;

    foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
      if( stripos($row['equipment_type'],'TA500') !== FALSE ):
        $realm = trim(strtolower($row['company']));
        $x     = explode('.',$row['ipaddress']);
        $oct3  = $x[0].'.'.$x[1].'.'.$x[2];
        $oct4  = $x[3];

        $x = explode('-',$row['systemname']);
        $y = trim(strtolower($x[1]));
        $z = trim(strtolower($x[2]));

        if(preg_match('/172\.16\.[0-9]+\.1[1-9]/',$row['ipaddress']) and $y == $z):
          $parentNodes[$oct3][$oct4] = $row;
        elseif($row['ipaddress'] != '172.16.67.32'):
          $childNodes[$oct3][] = $row;
        endif;
      else:
        $row['note'] = "wrong equipment type or bad ip";
        $misfits[] = $row;
      endif;
    }

    if( count($misfits) )
      $this->insert($misfits);

    foreach($misfits as $row):
      extract($row);
      $this->update_status($id,"Skipping - reason: {$note}");
    endforeach;

    self::cubbySet('parentNodes',$parentNodes);
    self::cubbySet('childNodes',$childNodes);

    foreach($childNodes as $oct => $rows):

      if( !isset($parentNodes[$oct])):
        $this->insert($rows,"No top tree ip found");
        continue;
      endif;

      $topTreeNode = $parentNodes[$oct]['11'];

      //For testing purposes only. Remove the following line when done
      if($topTreeNode['ipaddress'] != '172.16.148.11') continue;

      //$this->update_status();
      $topTreeInfo = self::fetch_command_results($topTreeNode['ipaddress']);


      if($topTreeInfo === FALSE):
        $this->insert($topTreeNode,"Unable to connect to host");
        continue;
      endif;

      foreach($rows as $row):
        //get tree and card details for this node ip
        $nodeip = isset($row['ipaddress']) ? trim($row['ipaddress']) : '';

        if($nodeip == ''):
          $this->insert($row,"Invalid IP found");
          continue;
        endif;

        $nodeData = self::isolate($nodeip,$topTreeNode['ipaddress'],$topTreeInfo);

        if($nodeData == FALSE):
          $this->insert($row,'failed to get node information');
          continue;
        endif;

        $nodeData['equipment_type'] = $row['equipment_type'];
        $nodeData['dslam_id']       = $row['id'];
        $nodeData['node_name']      = $row['node'];

        $ver = self::get_system_version($nodeip);
        $nodeData['system_version'] = !empty($ver) ? $ver : '?';

        if( !$this->insert($nodeData,'success') ):
          //file_put_contents();
        endif;

        --$rev;
        if($rev <= 0) break 2;
      endforeach;
    endforeach;
  }

  function insert($data,$note=NULL)
  {
    $rows = array();

    if( isset($data[0]) ):
      $dataSet = $data;
    else:
      $data['note'] = $note;
      $dataSet = array($data);
    endif;

    foreach($dataSet as $k => $data):
      if(isset($data['ipaddress'])):
        $data['nodeip']    = !empty($data['ipaddress']) ? $data['ipaddress'] : NULL;
        $data['node_name'] = !empty($data['node']) ? $data['node'] : NULL;
        $data['dslam_id']  = !empty($data['id']) ? $data['id'] : NULL;
      endif;

      if( (!isset($data['note']) or $data['note'] == '') and $note !== NULL ):
        $data['note'] = $note;
      endif;

      $values = array(
        'dslam_id'          => element('dslam_id',$data),
        'node_name'         => element('node_name',$data),
        'equipment_type'    => element('equipment_type',$data),
        'system_version'    => element('system_version',$data),
        'nodeindex'         => element('nodeindex',$data),
        'fedbyip'           => element('fedbyip',$data),
        'fedbyslot'         => element('fedbyslot',$data),
        'fedbyport'         => element('fedbyport',$data),
        'uplink'            => element('uplink',$data),
        'nodeip'            => element('nodeip',$data),
        'nodeCard'          => element('nodeCard',$data),
        'provisioned_links' => element('provisioned_links',$data),
        'active_links'      => element('active_links',$data),
        'spans'             => element('spans',$data),
        'note'              => element('note',$data),
      );

      $dataSet[$k] = $values;
    endforeach;

    return $this->ci->db->insert_batch('tool_system_inventory',$values,TRUE);
  }

  function synchronize()
  {
    $data = array();
    $cardTypes = array('GE','HDSL','T1','SHDSL');
        $rates['K'] = $rates['k'] = pow(10,3);
        $rates['M'] = $rates['m'] = pow(10,6);
        $rates['G'] = $rates['g'] = pow(10,9);

    $query = $this->ci->db->where('fedbyip IS NOT NULL',NULL,TRUE)
                          ->where('uplink < 1000000',NULL,TRUE)
                          ->get('tool_system_inventory');

    if( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
      foreach( $query->result() as $row ):
        $row->spans = (int)$row->spans;//in case this is NULL for some reason
        foreach($cardTypes as $ct):
          if( strpos($row->nodecard,$ct) === 0 ):
            $row->nodecard = strtolower($ct);
            break;
          endif;
        endforeach;

        $data[] = array(
          'id'=>$row->dslam_id,
          'equipment_type' => $row->system_version,
          'uplink_spans'   => $row->spans,
          'uplink_type'    => $row->nodecard,
          'uplink_speed'   => $row->spans ? ( ($row->spans - 1) * 1.5 ) : 0,
        );
      endforeach;

      $rowsUpdated = $this->ci->update_batch('dslams',$data,'id');

      //update status table on rows updated tool_system_inventory_status


      return $rowsUpdated;
    }

    return 0;
  }

  private function update_status($id,$note=NULL)
  {
    $data['dslam_id'] = $id;
    $data['note'] = $id;

    $dt = class_datetime();
    $data['datetime'] = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $this->ci->db->insert('tool_system_inventory_status',$data);
  }
}
```

Comment: can u tell me the actual function which starts the execution process? also tell me which section of data ia not coming properly.?

Comment: its a batch file that actually starts the execution of the script. the posted code works fine, that's not my issue. my issue is that I need to change or add to this file in order to get the data that I need. thanks again for taking a look at it.

Comment: What are some column names of the infos inserted in database? And what are the names of the missing fields? Can you show us the table schema?